# Should I broaden the scope of a question?

Tags: discussion, edits, editing-help

[What is the difference between Step Into and Step Over in the Eclipse debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580715/what-is-the-difference-between-step-into-and-step-over-in-the-eclipse-debugger)

This question seems to be a language agnostic question. Should I edit the question myself? Leave a comment for the OP? Or just ask another question for iOS even though know the answer...because it's a good question for the iOS community...

Comment: A question like that is likely to apply to quite a lot of languages, but it's not language agnostic.  There are plenty of languages that it *wouldn't* apply to.

Comment: @Servy really? What *kind* of languages wouldn't it apply to?

Comment: verilog is the first one that comes to mind.  And of course the specific semantics will vary between languages, considering that there are lots of different language features in different languages that can interact with those features.  Off of the top of my head, in C# you have properties, implicit conversion operators, async and iterator block state machines, and all sorts of other odd language constructs that can have weird (and in some cases, configurable by the IDE) interactions with those operations.

Comment: @Servy I _think_ if you are to think that way...then a lot of other questions may not be language agnostic. But let's just assume it really was language agnostic...should I have then edited the question because the answers are Java-oriented or it's just best not to touch it?

Comment: Considering that the question *isn't* language agnostic, how could one possibly explain how you would edit it to make it language agnostic?

Comment: Does an answer in java also explain the difference between the two methods in some other similar language? I'd expect it to for quite a few.

Comment: @Servy you didn't answer my comment. Forget this question. Consider [stack vs. heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap) but just consider that the person had also added a Java tag to and in the answers some wrote Java-related syntax. Should I then broaden the question or because there are 9 answers with Java syntax I shouldn't touch it?

Comment: @Honey The question doesn't have, and has never had, any java specific tag on it.  It has only ever asked about a language agnostic concept in a language agnostic way.  How is that in any way relevant to this situation.  And yes, I did answer your comment, I answered it by saying it's unanswerable.

Comment: wow! could somebody answer [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345372/should-i-broaden-the-scope-of-a-question?noredirect=1#comment456249_345372). I'm asking for a hypothetical situation.

Comment: The answer should first and formost answer the question asked. If the question was tagged java, C# answers to it wouln't be answering the question.

Comment: @honey as I said if a question has answers, leave it alone. Please ask another question if you want to know the answer to your other point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question has upvoted answers so, no you shouldn't change it because it's likely to make those answers invalid or at best only cover part of the question.

Ask and self-answer another similar question if you feel strongly about disseminating new information.